# is there any step by step method for a novice to add space to 14.04lts on acer c720 chromebook

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive, acer, disk, chromebook

I'm an absolute novice, but successfully installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS to my acer C720 chromebook following hugh greenbugs' method for dual boot. I also successfully ran out of disk space to install games. I hope to mount an external hard drive and wish to know if anyone would be willing to take me through the process step by step, with the aim that my newly mounted external drive will become the default installation path for all new installs. As a novice, I have no knowledge to return to you.

Comment: What's your current partition setup? Please post the output of `lsblk`. Are you installing games through Steam, the package manager, or stand-alone?

Answer (score -2):

Using a terminal

1. Plug in external hard drive
2. Change directory to hard drive using the cd command (directory is ~/"Name of hard drive in file system" without quotes) like this.

   ```
   cd ~/ExternalHardDrive
   ```
3. Run sudo apt-get to download games download games and enjoy.

Using Gdebi Package installer

1. Save package to hard drive
2. Open with GDebi

I hope this works!

Comment: -1 These steps are not clear. Plus external hard drives are never mounted under the home folder but under media. These instructions won't work.

Comment: thank you for the help, i found my answer in the form of a you tube video, but i do appreciate your help also.
How to Install steam games to an external or second hard disk drive in ubuntu Linux,
here is the video link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAgWug72-mQ thank you.